Using a search bar in an embedded google sheet in html document
I am creating a knowledge base for AutoCAD and I want to create a database of Issues and Solutions that users can search for. My simple solution was to create a database in google sheets and then have a search bar in a separate tab then lists issues and solutions when searched. The search bar works perfectly inside google sheets, but my oversight was that after embedding inside an html document, the drawing is not able to be edited, thus nothing can be typed into the search bar. Is there any way to make this work, or do I need to try a different path?
My coding skills are limited to html and css.
As stated, when starting the process I just assumed it would work, I was wrong. I don't really know what to try to make it work. I don't want to give anyone access to the actual spreadsheet and I want to keep everything inside the html document that is part of my AutoCAD "intranet" (just a website I keep locally on our server that is directly accessible inside of AutoCAD).

HTML and CSS are not enough here, you need a Google Apps Script.
